# how to iterate over 2 data frames for column.length - 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe_old that I want to transform into dataframe_new so that I can use it later on. Dataframe_old. I was able to create the structure dataframe_new so that I only have to fill in all the cells by searching the dataframe_old for each row/column pair. Column 1 has the key for each field id and value but I'm always out of bounds. I need to do something like "iterate" until column-1 but my attempts did not yield good results.

### These are the 2 dataframes I work with

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_old = {'seq': [100,100,100,100,1002,1002,1002,1003],
        'fieldID':['name','income','married','age','name','dollar','date','age'],
        'fieldValue':['George',100,'yes',38,'Martiness','5000','01/01/2000','45']
       }


data_new = {'seq': [100,1002,1003],
         'name': ['','',''],
         'income': ['','',''],
         'married': ['','',''],
         'age': ['','',''],
         'dollar': ['','',''],
         'date': ['','','']            
        }

df_old = pd.DataFrame(data_old)
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_new, index = data_new['seq'])
```

### I created a function to help me look up values

```
def find_value(sequence, field_identifier):
    '''
    search for values of fields from the original 
    export by using the sequence number and field id
    ''' 
    try:
        df_func = df_all.loc[(df_all['seq'] == sequence) & (df_all["fieldID"] == field_identifier)]
        field_value = df_func.at[0, "fieldValue"]
    except:
        field_value = ""
    
    return field_value
```

### Now I'm trying to combine everything but this ends up with out of bounds

```
for row in df_new.iterrows():
    cnt_col = 0
    first = True
    
    for column in df_new:
        if first:
            first = False
            continue
        else:
                fieldID = df.columns[cnt_col]
                seq = index
                
                df_new.loc[app, fieldID] = find_value(app, fieldID)

                cnt_col += 1
```

### This is what my expected result would be

```
data_expected = {'seq': [100,1002,1003],
                 'name': ['George','Martiness',''],
                 'income': [100,'5000',''],
                 'married': ['yes','',''],
                 'age': [38,'','45'],
                 'dollar': ['','',''],
                 'date': ['','01/01/2000','']            
        }

df_expected = pd.DataFrame(data_expected)
```

I tried to search the web but I'm stuck on this part and just can't get it to work.

Comment: you just try to fill df with dictionary data?

Comment: no, I used the dictionary to create an example dataframe to show my problem. The actual data is a very large csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you don't have multiple `fieldID` per `seq`:

```py
df_old.pivot(index="seq", columns="fieldID", values="fieldValue").reset_index().fillna('')
```

Outputs:

```py
fieldID   seq age        date  ... income married       name
0         100  38              ...    100     yes     George
1        1002      01/01/2000  ...                 Martiness
2        1003  45              ...
```

IF you do have multiple `fieldID`, and you wish to keep them all- this will agregate them into `list`:

```py
df_old.pivot_table(index="seq", columns="fieldID", values="fieldValue", aggfunc=list).reset_index()
```

Outputs:

```py
fieldID   seq   age  ... married         name
0         100  [38]  ...   [yes]     [George]
1        1002   NaN  ...     NaN  [Martiness]
2        1003  [45]  ...     NaN          NaN
```

Comment: thank you Grzegorz, I actually tried the pivot before without luck. It seems the aggfunc was the parameter I missed. The fieldID's per seq should be unique but it seems they are not. I used the drop_duplicates before but it seemed to now work for all entries. Even after using it the output shows a single value in the aggregated values which is the correct one and therefore tells me it is a duplicate. Either way, I know where to continue which is a big help!

this was the line I thought would take care of it but didn't
`df_old.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=True)`

Comment: No worries. Glad it worked :) I think to make your ```drop_duplicates``` work in this case - I would do: ```df_old.drop_duplicates(subset=["fieldID", "seq"], keep="first", inplace=True)``` (so it will track duplicates based only on the columns listed in ```subset```)

Comment: this worked! I also spend the morning finding the trouble maker rows and it turns out the drop_duplicates does not affect fieldValues with white space differences like "1234 test AVE   " and "1234 test AVE         " is not removed. But when I pivot the data it is flagged as a duplicate and throws an error.

Another way it worked was to use the strip function

`df_old['fieldValue'] = df_old['fieldValue'].str.strip()`

but I think using the subset is more robust going forward as the fieldValues per ID and Seq really should be unique anyway. 

I finally grasped the problem, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
d = (df_old.groupby('seq')
       .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['fieldID'],x['fieldValue'])))
       .to_dict())
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

Comment: thank you. I marked the answer as helpful but I don't have enough points so it does not show. Your solution worked as well in the example and also gave me a data frame for the entire dataset I'm working with. Unfortunately, it removed most of the data from the dataset. I suspect this is due to the duplicate index problem I'm investigating now.